# Script Only Runns Sucessfully 50-60% of the time

Tags: powershell

I'm sending a zip and the powershell script to computers in our organisation through our management software and then executing the powershell script through command prompt. The script unzips the folder, installs a program and adds some registry keys to the registry.

If the machine doesnt say that a policy is preventing execution of the script, it runs as expected, the program is installed and the registry keys are imported. But if it does give the warning and I set the policy to unrestricted I get the below error error. I am on Windows 8.1 and using Powershell 4.0

```
Id not be found.
At C:\Temp\tps1.ps1:5 char:9
+ Add-Type <<<< -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (system.io.compression.filesyste
m:String) [Add-Type], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands
.AddTypeCommand

Add-Type : Cannot add type. One or more required assemblies are missing.
At C:\Temp\tps1.ps1:5 char:9
+ Add-Type <<<< -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationExc
eption
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_LOAD_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman
ds.AddTypeCommand

Unable to find type [io.compression.zipfile]: make sure that the assembly conta ining this type is loaded.
At C:\Temp\tps1.ps1:7 char:25
+ [io.compression.zipfile] <<<< ::ExtractToDirectory($BackUpPath,     $destination) + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (io.compression.zipfile:String
) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The error seems very clear: **One or more required assemblies are missing...
+ Add-Type <<<< -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"**. It goes on to say it can't find **io.compression.zipfile**, which would clearly be that missing assembly. It even tells you how to fix it: Unable to find type [io.compression.zipfile]: make sure that the assembly conta ining this type is loaded.**.What part of that is unclear?

Comment: Well, Ken, as someone who is new to powershell scripting, how about "all of it"? Just because it is simple to you, Ken, does not mean that it is simple for everyone.

Comment: You're missing my point. SImply **reading the words of the error message** tells you both **exactly** what the problem is and **exactly** what you need to do to fix it. I ask again:  **What part of that is not clear to you? You have instructions to follow. What's preventing you from following them to resolve this?

Comment: No, you're missing my point. I am new, this is my first ever script and if it says to make sure an assembly containing the zipfile typie is loaded, then how do I do that?
Great, good for you for understanding this stuff. But either be helpful or dont bother.

Comment: Sorry. No reason to be rude. You might try instead searching for questions related to **missing assembly** and see what that turns up, since that's **exactly** what the error message says is the problem. Rather than being snarky with me, try to at least think, especially when someone points out to you specifically what you failed to read in the words of the error message. (And speaking of that, the words in the error message have meaning, but you'll never get that meaning if you don't bother to read the words and just run here to have someone hold your hand and read it for you.)

Comment: Mark you have no _right_ to expect an answer here. You haven't paid any money, the site offers no guarantees or other assurances of answers - it's a cooperative venture. If someone gives you an answer, then  you're well advised to understand the answer.  If some part of the answer is not clear to you, you can certainly ask specific clarifying questions if you've failed to find the answer after a reasonable amount of research.

Comment: Ken, you were the one being unhelpful and rude, I merely replied with the same destain with which you spoke to me.

Comment: User2460798, I didn't say I was demanding answers. I was saying that ken was just replying to make fun of me, much like you are. And again, if you aren't going to be helpful or even reasonable, you can go f**k yourself buddy. Kiran was helpful, insightful and as polite to me as I was to him. Unlike you and Ken who were both just being rude dicks for the sake of it.

Answer (score 1):

**on systems where .NET 4.5 is not installed, use:**

```
$BackUpPath = "C:\Temp\Install.zip"
$Destination = "C:\Temp"

$shell_app=new-object -com shell.application
$zip_file = $shell_app.namespace($BackUpPath )
$destination = $shell_app.namespace($Destination )
$destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items(),0x4)
```

**on systems with.NET 4.5 use:**

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory($BackUpPath, $destination)
```

A script on [technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Function-to-727d6200) combines the above 2 methods.

**On PowerShell V5 , this is much simplified:**

```
Expand-Archive $BackUpPath -destination $Destination
```

there are other ways to unzip files using 3rd party libraries such as 7-zip,  etc but that creates a dependency.

Note: Powershell execution policies can be set using group policy. see link [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/poshchap/archive/2015/01/02/execution-policy-and-group-policy.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Kiran, I appreciate your help.
Is there a way to include both in the same powershell script and getting the script to detect which command to execute?
I know I could do that in a bat pretty simply but I cant unzip a file via a batch file

Comment: Hi Mark..yes via the technet script i linked `https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Function-to-727d6200`...it does exactly what you are asking..just copy that function into your script and extract the zip file using the copied function...note: examples are included in that function

Comment: Thank you again Kiran :)